# How to change MasterDetailPage's Icon?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've tried this code in order to do that:

```
IsPresentedChanged += (sender, args) =>
{
    Master.Icon = IsPresented ? "nav_drawer_open.png" : "nav_drawer_closed.png";
};
```

This is my MasterPage:

```
<MasterDetailPage.Master>
  <ContentPage Title="FH" Icon="nav_drawer_closed.png" BackgroundColor="#333333">
```

But it doesn't work. If I debug it the Icon property is updated, but the actual Icon in the page is not.
Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: You should probably let the UI know that your property has been updated. So look at the INotifyPropertyChanged interface or Fody.PropertyChanged NuGetPackage

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Thanks, would you mind elaborating on that? Do I need that Fody package? Or can I just use the PropertyChanged one? Also, do I just use [ImplementPropertyChanged] and that'll work? Thanks.

Comment: Nope, just the PopertyChanged one is enough, and indeed apply the attribute you mentioned :)

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Thanks, I'll give it a try and get back to you.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Thanks, but it didn't work. Th behavior is still the same, the Icon is only updated when I change pages. I even tried to use ForceLayout and other refresh methods with no luck...

Comment: Maybe it is related to this issue: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=31664 which should be fixed in Xamarin.Forms 1.5, according to this release info: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/50813/xamarin-forms-1-5-0-released/p1

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk Thanks for sharing that, I'll take a look.